# link rel not working without http:// protocol

Tags: html, xhtml, hyperlink, opera

i'm trying to implement various semantic links on the website I'm working on.
For that, i try to put

```
    <link rel="start" href="index.html" />
```

In my head section.
Although the data is present in the web page, Opera does not seems to see it to show the navigation bar that should however be present.
Here is my full head section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>
    <title>Amnistie et compagnie</title>
    <link rel="start" href="index.html" />
    <link rel="previous" title="aaaa" href="365-gestes-pour-sauver-la-planxc3xa8te-2.html" />
    <link rel="next" title="aaa" href="5-best-data-visualization-proj.html" />
</head>
```

Furthermore, when replacing urls with absolute ones, it seems to work correctly. is there something I did wrong ?

I even tried using code samples like [this one](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum118/166.htm), but my navigation bar (which is set to show automatically) never appears, except when a href is an absolute url, what I radically don't want.

So, how can i specify link elements with relative urls ?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try the following doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Nothing changes, my navigation bar stays hidden.